# что делать, пишет, что Not connected to voice. Когда я подключаюсь к серверу, я забочусь о том, чтобы он мог воспроизводить музыку

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

```
@bot.command(name='join', help='Сообщает боту подключиться к голосовому каналу')
async def join(ctx):
if not ctx.message.author.voice:
await ctx.send("{} не подключен к голосовому каналу".format(ctx.message.author.name))
return
else:
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
await channel.connect()

@bot.command(name='leave', help='Чтобы заставить бота покинуть голосовой канал')
async def leave(ctx):
voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
if voice_client.is_connected():
await voice_client.disconnect()
else:
await ctx.send("Бот не подключен к голосовому каналу.")

@bot.command(name='play', help='Чтобы воспроизвести песню')
async def play(ctx, url):
try:
server = ctx.message.guild
voice_channel = server.voice_client
if not voice_channel:
await ctx.send("Бот не подключен к голосовому каналу. Используйте команду !join, чтобы подключить его.")
return

       `your text``your text` async with ctx.typing():
            filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
            print(f'Скачан файл: {filename}') 
            print('Начинаю воспроизведение:', filename)`your text`
            voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
            print('Аудио успешно начало воспроизводиться:', filename)
        await ctx.send('**Сейчас играет:** {}'.format(filename))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Ошибка воспроизведения аудио:', str(e))
        await ctx.send("Произошла ошибка при воспроизведении аудио.")

пробовал скачивать библиотеки, не помогло, 
указал полный путь к ffmpeg.exe это не помогло
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
await channel.connect()
```

Стоить заменить ваш код на этот -

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
await channel.connect()
```

Comment: теперь пишет это: Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexey\Desktop\TARGET-main\main.py", line 171, in play
    voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Users/Alexey/Desktop/TARGET-main/ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
  File "c:\Users\Alexey\Desktop\TARGET-main\myenv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 555, in play
    raise ClientException('Not connected to voice.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Not connected to voice.